# Solc Maximum call stack size exceeded at Object.$db [as dynCall_viiiiii]

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors, solidity

When I try to compile my contract I get a maximum call stack size exceeded error and cannot figure this out. Any insight would be greatly appreciated

Error

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.$db [as dynCall_viiiiii] (C:\Users\molli\Desktop\Coding\Udemy\Solidity Course\inbox\node_modules\[4msolc[24m\soljson.js:12:120931)
    at invoke_viiiiii (C:\Users\molli\Desktop\Coding\Udemy\Solidity Course\inbox\node_modules\[4msolc[24m\soljson.js:1:1118207)
    at Array.pva (C:\Users\molli\Desktop\Coding\Udemy\Solidity Course\inbox\node_modules\[4msolc[24m\soljson.js:13:29030)
    at Object.M9a [as dynCall_vi] (C:\Users\molli\Desktop\Coding\Udemy\Solidity Course\inbox\node_modules\[4msolc[24m\soljson.js:12:99033)
    at invoke_vi (C:\Users\molli\Desktop\Coding\Udemy\Solidity Course\inbox\node_modules\[4msolc[24m\soljson.js:1:1115011)
    at Array.xta (C:\Users\molli\Desktop\Coding\Udemy\Solidity Course\inbox\node_modules\[4msolc[24m\soljson.js:10:704784)
    at Object.Dfb [as dynCall_iii] (C:\Users\molli\Desktop\Coding\Udemy\Solidity Course\inbox\node_modules\[4msolc[24m\soljson.js:12:130740)
    at invoke_iii (C:\Users\molli\Desktop\Coding\Udemy\Solidity Course\inbox\node_modules\[4msolc[24m\soljson.js:1:1119442)
    at Array.vta (C:\Users\molli\Desktop\Coding\Udemy\Solidity Course\inbox\node_modules\[4msolc[24m\soljson.js:10:703080)
    at Object.Yfb [as dynCall_iiiiii] (C:\Users\molli\Desktop\Coding\Udemy\Solidity Course\inbox\node_modules\[4msolc[24m\soljson.js:12:131900)
```

Inbox.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Inbox {
    string public message;

    constructor(string initialMessage) public {
    message = initialMessage;
}
    
    function setMessage(string newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    }
}
```

compile.js

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf8');

module.exports = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts[':Inbox'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.
I was able to solve it by downgrading the module version.
The version when I succeed is below.

```
"ganache-cli": "^6.12.1",
"mocha": "^8.2.1",
"solc": "^0.4.17",
"web3": "^1.0.0-beta.26"
```